# How to determine probability of event as variable increases continously, and compare probability across treatments

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance

I have data values from an experiment in which a stimulus was presented to an animal at a distance and then moved closer to the animal,  and it was noted at what distances the animal responded. This was done with 2 groups of animals, a control and treatment group. How might I compare the likelihoods of animals in each group responding as the distance from stimulus decreases?

Comment: In one group you give stimulus at different distances, and in the control you do what...?

Comment: no both were exposed to stimulus at different distances, one was treated with a medication to increase perceptiveness before the stimulus exposure the other was not treated